# how to create HashMap or Arraylist which will contain all java class's constants

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have one Java constant file which contains around 1000 records and all are String type only
e.g.

```
public static String PF_EMPLOYER = "PF-Employer";
public static String ESI_EMPLOYER = "ESI-Employer";
public static String TOTAL_CTC = "Total CTC";
public static String INCENTIVE = "Incentive";
public static String PF_EMPLOYEE = "PF-Employee";
public static String ESI_EMPLOYEE = "ESI-Employee";
==and so on could be more than 1000=======
```

I just want all this String values in static ArrayList or HashMap where Integer in HashMap will be 0,1,2,3....1000.

I am stuck to find out any Effective way to complete this task, Even if Spring is providing any solution I am also ready to go with it.

**Its not possible for me to Move Constant file content in any Properties file.**

Note that I am using JDK 7 not possible to go for JDK 8.

Comment: Why would you possibly want to do this? Especially indexing with an integer? If you really have a good reason, you can use reflection to identify the static fields of a class and put the in a map. I doubt you'll get declaration-order, though.

Comment: Actually all these constants values are in excel sheet first row as header I want to validate header by parsing the excel sheet taking first row and all values want to match with these constants values and excel values must be in same order.

Comment: If those constants are finalised then generate your java code in excel, i.e. adding those in a hashmap.

Comment: Then do it with grep/sed. An arraylist/hashmap is totally the wrong way to go.

Comment: I can only use JAVA as after this process there are other many business logic which is already in java.

Comment: @NuriTasdemir Actually I am also having all the same values in iterator which is coming after parsing the Excel sheet first row and each values I want to match with this constant values in same order.

Comment: If you need to keep these stable, I would strongly recommend making the core values the integers -- or an enum -- and then generating a table which maps those to and from the corresponding string names. Counting on ordering is NEVER a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your requirement, the only *natural* way of doing what you want should be using reflection. If you class name was `ConstClass` it could be something like :

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Field field: ConstClass.class.getFields()) {
    if (String.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
        int modifiers = field.getModifiers();
        if (Modifier.isStatic(modifiers)) {
            map.put(field.getName(), (String) field.get(ConstClass.class));
        }
    }
}
```

That you get in `map` all fields containing `static String`.